# Vue.js Recursive Menu issue

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build a recursive menu in Vue.js, but I am getting an error and can't figure out whats wrong.
I have the following structure:

MenuList.vue

```
<template>
    <ul class="menu">
        <MenuLink v-for="menuItem in menuObject" :menuItem="menuItem" :key="menuItem.i"></MenuLink>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
import MenuLink from './MenuLink'

export default {
  name: 'MenuList',
  components: {MenuLink},
  props: ['menuObject'],
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And MenuLink.vue

```
<template>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            {{ menuItem.resourceKey }}
        </a>

        <MenuList :menuObject="menuItem.subMenuItems" v-if="menuItem.subMenuItems"></MenuList>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
  import MenuList from '@/components/common/menu/MenuList'

  export default {
    name: 'MenuLink',
    components: {MenuList},
    props: ['menuItem'],
    data () {
      return {
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But the MenuList inside MenuLink gives the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <MenuList> - did you register the component correctly?
For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
found in
---> <MenuLink> at src\components\common\menu\MenuLink.vue
       <MenuList> at src\components\common\menu\MenuList.vue
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register it globally in `app.js`. E.g.:

```
import MenuList from '@/components/common/menu/MenuList'
Vue.component('MenuList', MenuList);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Had to remove the MenuList components property value from my components too.